# File permissions while sending the file from one Linux host to another host

Tags: linux, permissions, umask, lftp, proftpd

One of the source servers is sending the files to destination servers using lftp. The umask setting in the destination host is `007`(in `proftpd.conf file`), so the files landing in the destination servers should be `660(007-666)`, but the permissions are varying.

What could be the factors contributing to the permissions of the files while transferring from one host to another using lftp?

Comment: The application that is writing the files on the destination server.

Comment: @GMaster: so, is it due to the umask setting on the destination server which defines the permission of the files arriving on the destination host?